# Trying to find image tags and replace the file path string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Every time a page loads, I need to run a script that goes through the page and finds all the img src file paths `(<img src="/RayRay/thisisianimage.png">)` and then add a string on to the file paths so it reads `<img src="/MainFolder/RayRay/thisisianimage.png">`.

My approach was to map the imgs and put them in an array, then iterate over the array and append the string to the url.

I've figured out how to map the images and put them into an array:

```
$('.contentArea img').map(function () {
    var b = $(this).find('src');
    return b.length ? b[0] : this;
})
```

Now I'm just having problems iterating over the array and appending the string. This is what I have right now and it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$.each('img', function (index, value) {
        $('/RayRay/').append('/MainFolder/');
    });
```

I've tried attaching to ato the attribute by using `.attr('src').append('/MainFolder/')` and that isn't working either. I think I just have the syntax wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

J

Comment: there is an important semantic difference between `append` and `prepend` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got multiple errors in your code, you can't use .find() to get the attribute like that, also you can't append the source string like that either.

Try this

```
$('.contentArea img').each(function () {
    this.src = '/MainFolder/' + this.src;
});
```

If you want to get all images src in an array and add /mainfolder/ to the array of images do this

```
var imgArr = $('.contentArea img').map(function () {
    var b = this.src//or $(this).attr('src')
    return b.length ? '/MainFolder/' + b : this;
}).get();
```

**How to use .attr()**

Set path like this

```
$('#myImage').attr('src','path here');
```

Get the attributes value like this

```
$('#myImage').attr('src');
```